# Is it OK to dissipate higher than rated power in an 0805 resistor for up to a minute?

Tags: resistors

In my project, I need to use an 0805 3.3kΩ resistor with a 125mW power rating (according to datasheet).

I need to apply 24V to the resistor for 1 minute, however this would dissipate 175mW, over the rated power for the resistor.

I want to know if it is OK to run the resistor over power for 1 minute?

Comment: Please don't shout! And a resistor does not "use Volts per minute!"

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Could you please take the time to write a good question and elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why don't you just get a resistor with the correct specs?

Comment: We generally run resistors at a maximum of half their rated power to obtain reliability in commercial equipment. As you increase dissipation to rated power, or to 150% of rated power, you lose reliability, quickly.

Comment: hello,my project normal operate voltage is 12V,power=43mW<125mW,but have a jump start test(24V/1min),it is power is 175mW>125mW,so could you teach me use this resistor in that case,it is OK?

Answer (score 3):

I *think* what you are trying to say is you are using a 3.3k resistor with a 24V system.

Your resistor is rated to 125mW, yet using the equation V^2/R, you have realised that there is 175mW dissipated.

If you want a reliable circuit, then just simply get a component with the correct specs. If you use a component outside of its rated specs, then the manufacturer cannot guarantee it will perform as needed. This component will heat up, change resistance due to heat and that can cause problems.

Bottom line is just buy the component with the correct specs. A quick search on any electronics distributor website will return loads of results for the component that will fit your requirements.

**Added due to comment**

> hello,my project normal operate voltage is 12V,power=43mW<125mW,but
>   have a jump start test(24V/1min),it is power is 175mW>125mW,so could
>   you teach me use this resistor in that case,it is OK?

Even with a normal operating voltage of 12V, you still have the 24V startup to deal with. Regardless of whether it is 10 seconds, 20 seconds, or 1 minute, the best thing to do is always plan for the worst case. If you are still in the design stage, swap it for an 1206 part, or perhaps 2 0805 in parallel. If you already have the PCB designed, then just buy a 250mW part.

Answer (score 0):

You may get away with over-rating a resistor for a few seconds, because the resistor will not have time to heat up appreciably. But over 1 minute an 0805 will heat up to over 150 degree C, which is usually the maximum temperature. This have a huge detrimental effect on its reliability.

The best solution is to use a part rated for more than 175mW, such as a 1206 sized resistor rated at 250mW, or two 0805's connected in series or parallel.

If you're committed to using an 0805 then you could look at a high temperature thin film resistor such as [this](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/130a/0900766b8130ada7.pdf) which is rated at 200mW.